# Rails Error Page using 301 Redirect - Chrome Doesn't Play Well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have my Rails environment configured to generate a dynamic error page based on an error code generated while browsing the site.

Currently I handle 404, 422 and 500 error codes through one page.   The issue is that when a 500 error is generated, Rails is automatically applying the 301 redirect.   This is problematic because error pages are not intended to be permanent, and Chrome is caching them.   This results in the user getting the 500 page, even after the error has been fixed.

I have done every Google search I can, and it appears that no one has had this specific issue (Note: I don't actually believe that).

Here's how my routes are configured:

```
# routing error pages
%w( 404 422 500 ).each do |code|
  get code, to: "errors#show", code: code
end
```

And here's my controller code (Note: pieces omitted for brevity):

```
if status_code == '404'
  Rails.logger.warn "Invalid endpoint request: #{request.original_fullpath}"
elsif status_code == '500'

  Rails.logger.warn "The 500 page was rendered.  Please check the logs prior to this message for stack trace and reporting."

  ...

end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render status_code.to_s, status: status_code }
  format.json { render json: status_code.to_s, status: status_code }
end
```

I have a page that generates an exception to test this calle `oh_noes`, this is the request redirect:

```
Request URL:http://192.168.42.42:3000/en/oh_noes
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:192.168.42.42:3000
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: There are already good blog posts about this for instance https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages

Comment: I have already read that one.  Like I said, I have done many searches on the topic.  All of them describe how to set it up, which I have already done.  The issue is the 301 and how to change it to a 302 so that it doesn't get cached.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I did follow the steps described within the blog post and the error view is rendered instantly when the error occours without any redirect.

Comment: Please read the post, it's not an error. I need the redirect to be a 302 which is a temporary redirect, not a 301 which is permanent, and gets cached. If you look in your dev console it will show you the kind of redirect.  You need to make sure your preserve your console log, so it will not clear between requests.   Look at the page request that is generating the error, and you will see that it was redirected as 301.  I need to know how to change this to 302.

Comment: I did look at my network traffic within firefox and into my logfile. When this error occours Rails directly renders the error action. For instance you call `/foo/bar` and `bar` does not exists Rails does not a redirect to a 404 action it renders directly `ErrorsController#not_found` no redirect to `/404` happens. So this redirect is in my point of view no Rails internal action. You create it by your own.

Comment: For whatever reason, mine is redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what went wrong.  Based on the comments from @slowjack2k, I realized that rails was redirecting in my situation, vs just rendering the error page in place of the page that caused the problem.  I looked at my routes, and realized that the error routes were inside of a :locale scope, so they were being routed as:

```
/en/500
/en/404
```

Rails has a requirement that they be routed from the root path.  So I moved them out of the locale scope, and now it's not redirecting anymore, it's just rendering the 500 in place of the requested page.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar but a bit different bug is that our 500 Error is constantly being cached via 301 permanent redirect to 500.html, turns out is that we do the redirection incorrectly

[image]

after change our route.rb from

```
get '/500', to: redirect('/500.html')
```

to

```
get '/500', to: redirect('/500.html', status: 302)
```